# Responsive Images - Defining

Tags: images, responsive

I am relatively new to working on themes with WordPress. I am wondering how I can change the responsive looker for images based on the screen size. I want to be able to change the min-size with @media to be able to define what happens to images. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean, the "responsive looker"? You want to add @ media rules for images -- do you mean on the front of your site, how do you add CSS rules with @ media queries in them?

Comment: Yes, How do I add meta queries to images through WordPress to have the site be more responsive with images? I know how to on normal webpages but WordPress is a little bit more challenging with knowing where to put the code.